# Why doesn't personal Tab in Teams App keep PHP $_SESSION data?

Tags: php, microsoft-teams, chamilo-lms

I have an App developed in "Developer Portal" in Teams with a personal tab embedding a LMS (Chamilo) which is working fine in a web browser, but inside a personal tab in Teams the data stored in PHP global variable $_SESSION is not keeping or is being deleted by the Tab o somehow by Teams.

I checked and I noticed that for some reason, the PHP global variable $_SESSION is getting empty in Teams

It was working fine till September last year, and it is working fine in Android Teams, but in desktop or web Teams I cannot login to my LMS or use PHP $_SESSIONS along PHP pages.

I'd like some help on how to configure my Team App or solve this problem.

Thank you!!!

Comment: PHP sessions require cookies, so it's likely that Teams is not hanging onto or submitting the session cookie properly.

Comment: Whether you choose to expose your tab within the channel or group, or personal scope, you must present an <iframe> HTML content page in your tab.
Teams app doesn't recognize sub iframes. Therefore, it'll not load if there is an iframe within the tab app.
Reference doc-https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs#declare-custom-tab-in-app-manifest

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, did you find any solution? How about using JWT token in the php app? Thanks